# Showing various images in a table HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a specific image every time I add a row to a table, using this template:

[LINK](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion)

However, when I add a `<td>` tag to the javascript code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
         $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png"></td>");
         $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
         i++; 
     });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
             $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
             i--;
         }
     });
});
```

The javascript no longer works, and I'm unable to add or remove rows.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you have any error in console?

Comment: @laker001 What do you mean by the javascript no longer works? Can you post your JS code? It will help!

Comment: Please post your JavaScript

Comment: The problem is because of the double quotes in the HTML string. You need to escape them. Also, your issue would have been much clearer if you added ***all*** code in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you show me how to do it?

Comment: "*the javascript no longer works*" - what javascript?  there's no javascript in the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @freedomn-m you can check it now!

Comment: Not sure what IDE you're using, but you might like to tweak the colours - it should be clear, as it is here in the question (where the src is shown in a different coliur), that you've terminated the string too soon.

Comment: Your image src code: <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png"> needs to escape quotes like this <img src=\"http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png\">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your line with this

```
$('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><img src=\"http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png\"></td>");
```

more specifically the line was causing the issue was

```
src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png"
```

you need to escape quotes like this

```
src=\"http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/delete-2-xxl.png\"
```

Comment: the image still does not load. could you please provide a working fiddle? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to load a specific image every time i add a row to a table,
>   using this template

In that case `img` id cannot be same.
 It need be unique.

Also note the `img` is a self closing HTML tag. You dont need to add `/` while closing it

Comment: Although what you said is true, I don't think it will solve OP's problem